# Sorting a linked list based on variable C

Tags: c, list, sorting, linked-list

I am trying to create a database of surveys where a linked list stores the surveys based on one of its variables. At the moment when I sort a survey it only places the node sorted after the first node (the head could be 999 and still first node) and also I am seeing an occasional infinite printing of elements when adding an element and then displaying all elements.

```
Sample Code:


void addElement(struct listelement** head_ptr)
{
    int data;
    int inputPPS;
    struct listelement *temp;
    struct listelement *newNode;



    if (*head_ptr == NULL)
    {

        addElement_AtStart(head_ptr);

    }

    else

    {

        temp = *head_ptr;
        newNode = (struct listelement*)malloc(sizeof(struct listelement));

        printf("\nPlease enter your PPS number (Number must be unique)\n");
        scanf("%d", &inputPPS);
        if (checkUnique(head_ptr, inputPPS) == 1) {

            newNode->surveyDetails.ppsNo = inputPPS;
            printf("\nPlease enter your first name:");
            scanf("%s", newNode->surveyDetails.fName);
            printf("\nPlease enter your last name:");
            scanf("%s", newNode->surveyDetails.lName);
            //printf("\nEnter email address: ");
            //do email validation
            //scanf("%s", newNode->studentData.email);

            printf("\nEnter current address: ");
            scanf(" %s", newNode->surveyDetails.address);//takes in the next 99 characters until a newline is found

            printf("\nPlease enter your :");
            scanf("%d", &newNode->surveyDetails.age);
            printf("\nPlease enter your yearly salary (as whole number):");
            scanf("%d", &newNode->surveyDetails.income);
            printf("\nHow many cigarrettes do you smoke a day? :");
            scanf("%d", &newNode->surveyDetails.ciggiesSmoked);
            printf("\nHow many units of alcohol do you drink in a day? :");
            scanf("%d", &newNode->surveyDetails.unitsTaken);
            printf("\nHow many time do you exercise every week? :");
            scanf("%d", &newNode->surveyDetails.timesExercised);


            while (temp != NULL)
            {
                if (sortedInsert(&head_ptr, newNode) == 1) {
                    printf("\nSurvey stored successfully\n");
                    break;
                }
                temp = temp->next;

            }

            //printf("\nSurvey didnt work successfully\n");


            //do sorted insert
        }
        else {//if pps is not unique recursively start function again prompting user
            printf("\nWe still value your feedback on this topic! If you believe you have entered your PPS incorrectly you can now try again!");
            addElement(head_ptr);
        }

    }
}

void addElement_AtStart(struct listelement** head_ptr)
{

    struct listelement *newNode;
    int inputPPS;

    newNode = (struct listelement*)malloc(sizeof(struct listelement));

    printf("\nWe will now take details from you for the survery...\n");
    printf("\nPlease enter your PPS number (Number must be unique)\n");
    scanf("%d", &inputPPS);
    if (checkUnique(head_ptr, inputPPS) == 1) {
        newNode->surveyDetails.ppsNo = inputPPS;
        //do unique check
        printf("\nPlease enter your first name:");
        scanf("%s", newNode->surveyDetails.fName);
        printf("\nPlease enter your last name:");
        scanf("%s", newNode->surveyDetails.lName);
        printf("\nEnter email address: ");
        //do email validation
        //scanf("%s", newNode->studentData.email);

        printf("\nEnter current address: ");
        scanf(" %s", newNode->surveyDetails.address);//takes in the next 99 characters until a newline is found

        printf("\nPlease enter your age:");
        scanf("%d", &newNode->surveyDetails.age);
        printf("\nPlease enter your yearly salary (as whole number):");
        scanf("%d", &newNode->surveyDetails.income);
        printf("\nHow many cigarrettes do you smoke a day? :");
        scanf("%d", &newNode->surveyDetails.ciggiesSmoked);
        printf("\nHow many units of alcohol do you drink in a day? :");
        scanf("%d", &newNode->surveyDetails.unitsTaken);
        printf("\nHow many time do you exercise every week? :");
        scanf("%d", &newNode->surveyDetails.timesExercised);
    }
    else {//if pps is not unique recursively start function again prompting user
        printf("\nWe still value your feedback on this topic! If you believe you have entered your PPS incorrectly you can now try again!");
        addElement_AtStart(head_ptr);
    }


    //no sorted insert if file has surveys sorting will be done in addElement

    newNode->next = *head_ptr;

    *head_ptr = newNode; // transfer the address of newNode' to'head'

}
int sortedInsert(struct listelement** head_ref, struct listelement* newNode)
{
    struct listelement* temp;
    /* Special case for the head end */
    if (*head_ref == NULL || (*head_ref)->surveyDetails.ppsNo >= newNode->surveyDetails.ppsNo)
    {
        newNode->next = *head_ref;
        *head_ref = newNode;
        printf("At head");
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        /* Locate the node before the point of insertion */
        temp = *head_ref;
        while (temp->next != NULL &&
            temp->next->surveyDetails.ppsNo < newNode->surveyDetails.ppsNo)
        {
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        newNode->next = temp->next;
        temp->next = newNode;
        return 1;
    }
    printf("failed");
}
int checkUnique(struct listelement *head_ptr, int inputPPS) {
    int nodeNum = 0;
    struct listelement *temp;
    temp = head_ptr;



    while (temp != NULL)
    {
        if (nodesAdded == 0) {
            nodesAdded++;
            printf("\n First node so is unique");
            return 1;
        }
        if (temp->surveyDetails.ppsNo== inputPPS )
        {
            printf("\n There is a user in the survey system with this PPS Number.");
            return 0;
        }
        nodeNum++;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    printf("\nPPS Number is unique. Continuing...\n We will now ask you for your survey details... ");

    nodesAdded++;
    return 1;

}
```

Edit: 
Revised code so far, at the moment I am having an issue where the variables are taken in however the node is not correctly assigned as the head node, this was found in debugging where upon adding a second element head_ptr would have strange values (not the ones entered).

```
void addElement(struct listelement** head_ptr)
{
    int data;
    int inputPPS;
    struct listelement *temp;
    struct listelement *newNode;



    if (*head_ptr == NULL)
    {

        addElement_AtStart(head_ptr);

    }

    else

    {

        temp = *head_ptr;
        newNode = (struct listelement*)malloc(sizeof(struct listelement));

        printf("\nPlease enter your PPS number (Number must be unique)\n");
        scanf("%d", &inputPPS);
        if (checkUnique(&head_ptr, inputPPS) == 1) {

            newNode->surveyDetails.ppsNo = inputPPS;
            printf("\nPlease enter your first name:");
            scanf("%s", newNode->surveyDetails.fName);
            printf("\nPlease enter your last name:");
            scanf("%s", newNode->surveyDetails.lName);
            //printf("\nEnter email address: ");
            //do email validation
            //scanf("%s", newNode->studentData.email);

            printf("\nEnter current address: ");
            scanf(" %s", newNode->surveyDetails.address);//takes in the next 99 characters until a newline is found

            printf("\nPlease enter your :");
            scanf("%d", &newNode->surveyDetails.age);
            printf("\nPlease enter your yearly salary (as whole number):");
            scanf("%d", &newNode->surveyDetails.income);
            printf("\nHow many cigarrettes do you smoke a day? :");
            scanf("%d", &newNode->surveyDetails.ciggiesSmoked);
            printf("\nHow many units of alcohol do you drink in a day? :");
            scanf("%d", &newNode->surveyDetails.unitsTaken);
            printf("\nHow many time do you exercise every week? :");
            scanf("%d", &newNode->surveyDetails.timesExercised);


            while (temp != NULL)
            {
                if (sortedInsert(head_ptr, newNode) == 1) {
                    printf("\nSurvey stored successfully\n");
                    break;
                }
                temp = temp->next;

            }

            //printf("\nSurvey didnt work successfully\n");


            //do sorted insert

        }
        else if (checkUnique(&head_ptr, inputPPS) == 0){//if pps is not unique recursively start function again prompting user
            printf("\nWe still value your feedback on this topic! If you believe you have entered your PPS incorrectly you can now try again!");
            free(newNode);
        }

    }
}

void addElement_AtStart(struct listelement** head_ptr)
{

    struct listelement *newNode;
    int inputPPS;

    newNode = (struct listelement*)malloc(sizeof(struct listelement));

    printf("\nWe will now take details from you for the survery...\n");
    printf("\nPlease enter your PPS number (Number must be unique)\n");
    scanf("%d", &inputPPS);
    if (checkUnique(head_ptr, inputPPS) == 1) {
        newNode->surveyDetails.ppsNo = inputPPS;
        //do unique check
        printf("\nPlease enter your first name:");
        scanf("%s", newNode->surveyDetails.fName);
        printf("\nPlease enter your last name:");
        scanf("%s", newNode->surveyDetails.lName);
        printf("\nEnter email address: ");
        //do email validation
        //scanf("%s", newNode->studentData.email);

        printf("\nEnter current address: ");
        scanf(" %s", newNode->surveyDetails.address);//takes in the next 99 characters until a newline is found

        printf("\nPlease enter your age:");
        scanf("%d", &newNode->surveyDetails.age);
        printf("\nPlease enter your yearly salary (as whole number):");
        scanf("%d", &newNode->surveyDetails.income);
        printf("\nHow many cigarrettes do you smoke a day? :");
        scanf("%d", &newNode->surveyDetails.ciggiesSmoked);
        printf("\nHow many units of alcohol do you drink in a day? :");
        scanf("%d", &newNode->surveyDetails.unitsTaken);
        printf("\nHow many time do you exercise every week? :");
        scanf("%d", &newNode->surveyDetails.timesExercised);
    }
    else {//if pps is not unique recursively start function again prompting user

        printf("\nWe still value your feedback on this topic! If you believe you have entered your PPS incorrectly you can now try again!");
        free(newNode);

    }


    //no sorted insert if file has surveys sorting will be done in addElement

    newNode->next = *head_ptr;

    *head_ptr = newNode; // transfer the address of newNode' to'head'


    free(newNode);
}
int sortedInsert(struct listelement** head_ref, struct listelement* newNode)
{
    struct listelement* temp;
    /* Special case for the head end */
    if (*head_ref == NULL || (*head_ref)->surveyDetails.ppsNo >= newNode->surveyDetails.ppsNo)
    {
        newNode->next = *head_ref;
        *head_ref = newNode;
        printf("At head");
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        /* Locate the node before the point of insertion */
        temp = *head_ref;
        while (temp->next != NULL &&
            temp->next->surveyDetails.ppsNo < newNode->surveyDetails.ppsNo)
        {
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        newNode->next = temp->next;
        temp->next = newNode;
        return 1;
    }
    printf("failed");
}
int checkUnique(struct listelement *head_ptr, int inputPPS) {
    int nodeNum = 0;
    struct listelement *temp;
    temp = head_ptr;



    while (temp != NULL)
    {
        if (nodesAdded == 0) {
            nodesAdded++;
            printf("\n First node so is unique");
            return 1;
        }
        if (temp->surveyDetails.ppsNo== inputPPS )
        {
            printf("\n There is a user in the survey system with this PPS Number.");
            return 0;
        }
        nodeNum++;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    printf("\nPPS Number is unique. Continuing...\n We will now ask you for your survey details... ");

    nodesAdded++;
    return 1;

}
```

Comment: Your whole `while (temp->next...)... if (sortedInsert...break... temp->next= newNode` has a bad odor. Go over the logic again.

Answer (score 0):

`addElement` calls `sortedInsert` to insert `newNode` into the sorted position, but then it re-inserts `newNode` after `temp` once `sortedInsert` returns.  So, the node is always inserted immediately after the first node, and whichever node it was previously inserted after will still be pointing to it, so the list will cycle without end.

Your code also leaks memory in `addElement` if `checkUnique` fails, and will insert a garbage node in `addElement_AtStart` for the same reason.  You are unnecessarily special-casing the case of inserting the first element into the list, and have replicated all the code that asks the questions; this is a really bad thing to do.  Also, `checkUnique` modifies global state (`nodesAdded`), even though the calling code may decide to not actually insert the node.

Edit: I've been called out in the past for providing working code instead of answering the question.  I believe that the advice I gave above does fix the problem, but there are additional problems that are causing it to fail still.  I created a simple, working example [here](http://pastebin.com/wgGmJRnC), so you can look at it only if you really want to...  If you do look at it, please study it carefully to see how the special and duplicate cases have been eliminated.

Comment: would you be able to expain what you mean by the garbage node? I have removed the code that reinserts the newNode I believe however I am having the same errors.

Comment: `addElement_AtStart` allocates a new node, then asks for pps and if `checkUnique` does not return 1, it calls `addElement_AtStart` again.  Once that returns, it inserts the uninitialized `newNode` into the list anyway.

Comment: I have tried adding in free(temp) in the else clause for check unique however it did not provide a resolution. Is there a particular way I should be unallocating the node?

Comment: The garbage entry / memory leak would only occur when `checkUnique` failed, which won't happen if you enter unique pps values. I was just pointing that out as an additional problem, not necessarily causing your immediate issue.  Can you post your updated code?

Comment: Code with some alterations is up now. When I am assigning the first node to the list it is not accepting the values using breakpoints it is only getting to the end of the function where something goes wrong. At the moment I am trying to make checkUnique fail as I want to be sure no duplicates are possible so at the moment Iv been making surveys with the same pps to test @pat